# Topological sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, graph

The algorithm works in steps:

1. Produce the graph in the form of an adjacency list

   e.g. this graph

   ```
   0 - - 2
       \
         1 -- 3
   ```

   produces this adjacency list

   ```
   {0: [], 1: [0], 2: [0], 3: [1, 2]}
   ```

   0 depends on nothing, 1 depends on 0 etc..
2. Iterate through the graph and find nodes that does not have any dependencies

Questions:

1. What should the correct running time be for a well implemented topological sort. I am seeing different opinions:

   [Wikipedia says: \$O(log^2(n)\$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Complexity)

   [Geeksforgeeks says: \$O(V+E)\$](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/)
2. My implementation is running at \$O(V*E)\$. Because at worst, I will need to loop through the graph V times and each time I will need to check E items. How do I make my implementation into linear time.

```
def produce_graph(prerequisites):
    adj = {}
    for course in prerequisites:
        if course[0] in adj:
            # append prequisites
            adj[course[0]].append(course[1])
        else:
            adj[course[0]] = [course[1]]

    # ensure that prerequisites are also in the graph
    if course[1] not in adj:
        adj[course[1]] = []

    return adj

def toposort(graph):
    sorted_courses = []
    while graph:

        # we mark this as False
        # In acyclic graph, we should be able to resolve at least
        # one node in each cycle
        acyclic = False
        for node, predecessors in graph.items():
            # here, we check whether this node has predecessors
            # if a node has no predecessors, it is already resolved,
            # we can jump straight to adding the node into sorted
            # else, mark resolved as False
            resolved = len(predecessors) == 0
            for predecessor in predecessors:
                # this node has predecessor that is not yet resolved
                if predecessor in graph:
                    resolved = False
                    break
                else:
                    # this particular predecessor is resolved
                    resolved = True

            # all the predecessor of this node has been resolved
            # therefore this node is also resolved
            if resolved:
                # since we are able to resolve this node
                # We mark this to be acyclic
                acyclic = True
                del graph[node]
                sorted_courses.append(node)

        # if we go through the graph, and found that we could not resolve
        # any node. Then that means this graph is cyclic
        if not acyclic:
            # if not acyclic then there is no order
            # return empty list
            return []

    return sorted_courses

graph = produce_graph([[1,0],[2,0],[3,1],[3,2]])
print toposort(graph)
```

Comment: Is your indentation messed up in `produce_graph`?  I think the second `if` test should be in the `for` loop.

Comment: Please read the whole sentence from Wikipedia: "... it can be computed in O(log^2 n) time on a parallel computer using a polynomial number O(n^k) of processors, for some constant k."

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31010922/3001761) - it doesn't seem like you actually want a *review* in terms of the scope of this site.

Answer (score 2):

**Documentation**

Please add documentation to tell what the function is supposed to do and what input it is expecting.

**Avoid repetition**

In `produce_graph`, you repeat `course[0]` many times which smells like something wrong.

It can be rewritten :

```
def produce_graph(prerequisites):
    adj = {}
    for course in prerequisites:
        first, second = course[0], course[1]
        if first in adj:
            # append prequisites
            adj[first].append(second)
        else:
            adj[first] = [second]

    # ensure that prerequisites are also in the graph
    if second not in adj:
        adj[second] = []

    return adj
```

**Using the right tool**

What you are doing in `produce_graph` can be easily achieved using the `set_default` function :

```
adj = {}
for course in prerequisites:
    first, second = course[0], course[1]
    adj.setdefault(first, []).append(second)
```

(One might also suggest using `defaultdict`, I'll let you pick your favorite).

Using the right tool is also choosing the right data structure. It would probably make sense for `produce_graph` to take a list of tuples. Also, if you know that each elements contains 2 elements, you can use tuple unpacking like this :

```
for course in prerequisites:
    first, second = course
```

or

```
for first, second in prerequisites:
    adj.setdefault(first, []).append(second)
```

**Avoid premature optimisation/keep it simple**

Regarding :

```
        resolved = len(predecessors) == 0
        for predecessor in predecessors:
            # this node has predecessor that is not yet resolved
            if predecessor in graph:
                resolved = False
                break
            else:
                # this particular predecessor is resolved
                resolved = True
```

At the beginning, you iterate resolved to True if `predecessors` is True, False otherwise. I think this does the same as :

```
        resolved = True
        for predecessor in predecessors:
            # this node has predecessor that is not yet resolved
            if predecessor in graph:
                resolved = False
                break
```

As resolved will be False if and only if an element verifies the property `in graph`.

Also, this can be rewritten using builtin all/any :

```
        if all(p not in graph for p in predecessors):
```